# Libevent syncing data on two devices

Tags: c++, synchronization, libevent

I'm planning on creating an simple HTTP file transferring server which would sync the data inside a folder between an android tablet and pc. I have recently come to know that Libevent support HTTP apis. Is what I'm planning achievable? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "HTTP server which would sync the data inside a folder between a android tablet and pc". Do you want to sync folder between devices using HTTP protocol?

Comment: yeah exactly what I want to do.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel... either use git for small files or rsync for big files, tunneled in ssh to sync between the devices.

Comment: @Zmo: rsyn was my first choice but since I want this app to be platform independent and free of commercial implementation of rsync and the likes , also this application will be used for media file ( thus there is no need for rsync's delta compression). So rsync does not seem to fit properly.  I did not consider git or ssh :P

Comment: @ZMO: The other device may be a tablet or cell phone as well !

Comment: for media files, forget about git, but using scp can fit fine. If you plan to work with an android tablet of cellphone, it may be possible to use them. (I hope without rooting the device)